# Why won't all of my new notes inherit the button function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following JavaScript code that is triggered once DOM is loaded:

```
const add_note = () => {
 // Creates a new note and its props
 const new_note = document.createElement("div");
 const new_input = document.createElement("input");
 const new_form = document.createElement("form");
 const new_ol = document.createElement("ol");
 const new_button = document.createElement("button");

 //Populates the new note with inputs and checkboxes
 for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   let new_li = document.createElement("li");
   let new_checkbox = document.createElement("input");
   new_checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
   let new_li_input = document.createElement("input");
   new_li_input.classList.add("li_input");
   new_ol.appendChild(new_li);
   new_li.appendChild(new_checkbox);
   new_li.appendChild(new_li_input);
 }

 //New note's settings
 new_note.setAttribute("id", "note");
 new_note.classList.add("note");
 new_note.appendChild(new_input);
 new_input.classList.add("note_input");
 new_input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Note's title");
 new_note.appendChild(new_form);
 new_form.appendChild(new_ol);
 new_ol.setAttribute("id", "ol_id");
 new_note.appendChild(new_button);
 new_button.classList.add("more_items");
 new_button.setAttribute("id", "more_items");

 //Inserts the new note and button
 const note_block = document.getElementById("notes");
 note_block.appendChild(new_note);
 const button = document.getElementById("more_items");
 button.addEventListener("click", add_more_items);
 button.innerHTML = "+";
};
```

However, once the notes are created, only the first note button inherits its functions as seen on the following image:
[Code loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjKmJ.png)

I've tried about everything I can but couldn't figure it out. Anyway thanks in advance.

Comment: [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) will only return a single element. Did you mean to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs are unique in html, you can't have multiple elements with the same id

Either remove these lines, make them into classes, or somehow distinguish them:

```js
new_note.setAttribute("id", "note");
...
new_ol.setAttribute("id", "ol_id");
...
new_button.setAttribute("id", "more_items");
```

And just refer to the button with the variable:

```js
const note_block = document.getElementById("notes");
note_block.appendChild(new_note);
new_button.addEventListener("click", add_more_items);
new_button.innerHTML = "+";
```

You could actually even move these last two lines up to the rest of your code before appending the note block.

Comment: What do you mean by making them into classes? Can one create div tags (notes in my case) from a class constructor?

Comment: @LUCASDEBIAZIFERREIRA was referring to html class attribute, not es6